# invalid conversion from ‘int (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I have two classes like this
**driver.cpp** which have method void **loadFile** call another method int **initialDragonXPos** from **util.cpp**

```
int loadFile(Dragon * dragons) 
{
    int index = 0;
    index++;
    dragons[index].setPosX(initialDragonXPos);
}
```

And method int **initialDragonXPos** like this

```
int initialDragonXPos( )
{
    int pos = rand( ) % (MAX_DRAGON_XPOS * 2);
    pos = pos + MIN_DRAGON_XPOS;

    return pos;
}
```

And also this is **setPosX** method

```
void Dragon::setPosX(int posX)
{
    this->posX = posX;
}
```

So I get the error : **invalid conversion from ‘int (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]**. So how I can fix it

Comment: You must **call** a function to get its return-value... even if it takes no arguments. Otherwise you just get its address, which is of course a different type.

Comment: And what if `index++` is out of bounds for `dragons`? You should check for that (or preferably use a C++ container class, such as `std::vector`).

Comment: @crashmstr: `std::vector` normally does not check in release-mode.

Comment: @Deduplicator: unless you use later MSVC compilers which turn **on** bounds checking by default in release builds at, of course, a great performance expense.

Comment: @Deduplicator What I mean is that currently he does not know (locally) how big `dragons` is, and cannot check `index` for being out of bounds without passing the size, using a global, or a `#define`. Using `std::vector` correctly would change the code quite a bit and he might not even need to index directly, or at least be able to know the size of the data.

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks. I already control about index but I didn't show fully code here. but the problem is definitely not invoke to index. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Deduplicator Sr I don't really understand. Can you tell me what I need to change. Right in the line dragons[index].setPosX(initialDragonXPos) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `dragons[index].setPosX(initialDragonXPos);` is attempting to assign the *address* of the function `initialDragonXPos` which causes a compile error due to mismatched types.

You need to actually invoke the function. Change to:

`dragons[index].setPosX(initialDragonXPos());`

Comment: Sr. I still don't get it. Can you show me. I thought the setPosX need INT parameter and also initialDragonXPos is return INT so it seem like ok but it not @Bathsheba

Comment: `initialDragonXPos()` *returns* an `int` which is passed to `setPosX`. Look at my answer carefully. Note well the `()` just after `initialDragonXPos`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Sr I didn't look carefully about your comment. Haha this a very first time I'm in this community. Thanks a bunch